# PostgreSQL Waiting List Query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table that contains WaitingListPosition records, which is essentially a ticket to signify a user is waiting to join a membership for a Club, which has its own record in the Clubs table. In the WaitingListPositions table there are multiple positions for various Clubs. This is what the table currently looks like with a SELECT query:

```
 id | club_id | location_id | user_id | child_id |          created_at           
----+---------+-------------+---------+----------+-------------------------------
  2 |       8 |           3 |      10 |          | 2021-07-05 12:49:24.036091+00
  4 |       8 |           3 |      33 |          | 2021-07-05 12:55:57.54674+00
  5 |       9 |           5 |         |        5 | 2021-07-05 12:58:16.319837+00
```

I have an API that returns a list of WaitingListPosition objects in array, which returns all the WaitingListPositions that user has. I need to get the following data out but have been unsuccessful:

- Each object must contain all the WaitingListPosition data
- The current position in the waiting list (the list is ordered by created_at *(timestamp)* field)
- The total amount of WaitingListPositions that correspond to the same Club of the current WaitingListPosition object

I need to figure out a query that would produce the following results for the API (using the previous data as example):

```
 id | club_id | location_id | user_id | child_id |          created_at           | position  |  total_count
----+---------+-------------+---------+----------+-------------------------------+-----------+---------------
  2 |       8 |           3 |      10 |          | 2021-07-05 12:49:24.036091+00 |     1     |       2
  4 |       8 |           3 |      33 |          | 2021-07-05 12:55:57.54674+00  |     2     |       2
  5 |       9 |           5 |         |        5 | 2021-07-05 12:58:16.319837+00 |     1     |       1
```

I was able to successfully get the total_count into the query without any problems, perhaps not the most efficient way, but by running a subquery of all the memberships where the user/child is involved, and then getting the count for each location. Worked fine. I just cant for the life of me get the position...

This is what I've got so far, obviously the position is incorrect and is taking the row number of the wrong data.

```
WITH total_counts AS
        (SELECT club_id,
            COUNT(id)
            FROM ClubWaitingListPositions
            WHERE club_id = ANY((SELECT DISTINCT(club_id)
                FROM ClubWaitingListPositions
                WHERE user_id = $1
                OR (child_id = ANY(SELECT id
                    FROM Children
                    WHERE $1 = ANY(parents)))))
            GROUP BY club_id),
        positions AS (SELECT results.*,
            ClubLocations.location_name AS location_name,
            Clubs.name AS club_name
            FROM (SELECT ClubWaitingListPositions.*,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY created_at) AS position,
                (SELECT count
                    FROM total_counts
                    WHERE club_id = ClubWaitingListPositions.club_id)
                AS total_count
                FROM ClubWaitingListPositions) results
                INNER JOIN ClubLocations ON ClubLocations.id = results.location_id
                INNER JOIN Clubs ON ClubLocations.club_id = Clubs.id
                WHERE (user_id = $1)
                OR (child_id = ANY(SELECT id FROM Children WHERE $1 = ANY(parents))))
        SELECT positions.*,
            CONCAT(Users.first_name, ' ', Users.last_name) AS member_name
            FROM positions
            INNER JOIN Users ON Users.id = positions.user_id
            WHERE user_id IS NOT NULL
        UNION
        SELECT positions.*,
            CONCAT(Children.first_name, ' ', Children.last_name) AS member_name
            FROM positions
            INNER JOIN Children ON Children.id = positions.child_id
            WHERE child_id IS NOT NULL
        ORDER BY created_at DESC
```

Any help appreciated ! :)